Pyspark - Converting String to Timestamp populated as Null
I have dataframe df with a "joiningdate" string column with the value 2023-07-19T00:00Z. I want to convert this to a timestamp as 2023-07-19 00:00:00. I've tried many ways but it get populates as null. Please let me know how to get the desired result.
df.withColumn("joiningdate", to_timestamp(df["joiningdate"], "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
                   .cast("timestamp"))


the time part of the timestamp does not have seconds and the format you provided has seconds

You can try:
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn("joiningdate", F.to_timestamp(df["joiningdate"], "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'"))


